# How are python module paths translated to filesystem paths?

Tags: python, pytest, python-module

This may seem like a simple question, but I haven't found an answer that explains the behavior I'm seeing. Hard to provide a simple repro case but I basically have a package structure like this:

`a.b.c`
`a.b.utils`

I have one project that has files in `a.b.c.` (let's call this `aux_project`) and another that has files in `a.b.d`, `a.b.utils`, etc (call it `main_project`). I'm trying to import `a.b.utils` inside pytest tests in the first project, using `tests_require`. This does not work because `a.b` is for some reason sourced from inside `aux_project/a/b/__init__.pyc` instead of the virtualenv and it shadows the other package (i.e. this `a.b` only has a `c` in it, not `d` or `utils`). This happens ONLY in the test context. In ipython I can load all packages fine, and they are correctly loaded from virtualenv.

What's weirder is that if I simply *delete* the actual directory, the tests do load the pycs from virtualenv and everything works (I need that directory, though)

python==2.7.9

What is going on?

Comment: I should add that no PYTHONPATH is set explicitly, and both ipython and the tests are running in the same venv

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was simply that the cwd is prepended to the PYTHONPATH. `sys.path.pop(1)` (0 is the tests dir, prepended by pytest) resolved the behavior.